# I can't access to the JSON file from URL in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web, url

I want to download JSON from URL of dextools URL is

> https://www.dextools.io/chain-bsc/api/Pancakeswap/pools?timestampToShow=1669287222&range=1

my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request 
import json

download_url = "https://www.dextools.io/chain-bsc/api/Pancakeswap/pools?timestampToShow=1657123280&range=1" 
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'}

req = Request(download_url, headers=header)
webpage = urlopen(req).read() 
data = json.loads(webpage)
```

Comment: When I enter your link it says `Access denied You cannot access www.dextools.io. Refresh the page or contact the site owner to request access.`

If side requires login, then you have to login in your code as well, in order to access desired json

Comment: But when I copy this link in the download manager, the json file is downloaded

Comment: I also get permission denied. If you just need the json then since you have it make it a static file on the server. If it is needed from that site then please describe the download manager.

Comment: I also get permission denied. If you just need the json then since you have it make it a static file on the server. If it is needed from that site then please describe the download manager.

Comment: So, and why did you tag this with both python 2 and 3?